# Google cloud datastore: multiple save calls only creating one entity

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I have a google cloud function with a http trigger that I want to use to save information into datastore.

When I send information to it, the first request will work and create an entity in datastore, but following requests will not.

Here is my function:

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')
const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: 'XXXX'
})
const myKey = datastore.key({namespace: 'mynamespace', path: ['mypath']})

exports.metrics = async (req, res) => {
    let type = req.body.type
    let user = req.body.user
    let date = req.body.date || new Date().toISOString()

    await datastore
        .upsert({
            key: myKey,
            data: {
                type,
                user,
                date
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            res.status(200).send(response)

        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send(err)
        })

}
```

I don't get an error. I always get a 200 response, but the response varies.
For the requests that work, the mutationResults contain information about the key. In those requests that don't work, the mutationResults key is null.

So why do only some requests work?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me...

With a caveat: updates to a single (Datastore) entity used to be limited to 5/sec (!?) but this appears to have been relaxed|improved but remains limited:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#updates_to_an_entity

I assume you're using "Datastore" (not "Firestore Native") mode because you're using namespaces; the code does not error but does not work in Native mode.

> **NOTE** If you're deploying as a Cloud Function, you needn't provide an object with the `project` value when newing Datastore as this value is provided by the environment.

> **NOTE** one other thing to bear in mind is that, because the `key` is a global constant for **each** instance, you'll be able to generate multiple entities if you scale to >1 Cloud Functions instances

```js
/* jshint esversion: 10 */
/* globals exports,require */

const { Datastore } = require("@google-cloud/datastore");
const datastore = new Datastore();

const key = datastore.key({
    namespace: "ns",
    path: ["path"]
});
console.log(`${key}`);

exports.metrics = async (req, res) => {
    let type = req.body.type;
    let user = req.body.user;
    let date = req.body.date || new Date().toISOString();

    await datastore.upsert({
        key: key,
        data: {
            type,
            user,
            date
        }
    }).then(response => {
        res.status(200).send(response);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
};
```

and `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "62718657",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/datastore": "6.0.0"
    }
}
```

and:

```sh
gcloud functions deploy metrics \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--entry-point=metrics \
--trigger-http \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--region=us-central1 \
--runtime=nodejs10
```

I (appear to only) get 200s when the Functions|upsert succeeds.

I can force upsert contention with:

```sh
ENDPOINT=$(\
  gcloud functions describe metrics \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)")

for t in {1..100}
do
  printf "%s\n" $(curl --silent ${ENDPOINT})
done
```

Which generates:

```
{
  "code":10,
  "details":"too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.",
  "metadata":{
    "internalRepr":{},
    "options":{}
  }
}
```

and:

```sh
gcloud functions logs read --project=${PROJECT}
LEVEL  NAME     EXECUTION_ID  TIME_UTC                 LOG
       metrics  gn3g6prcri96  2020-07-07 17:38:08.736  undefined
       metrics  ogcineo00ryu  2020-07-07 17:38:08.743  failure: Error: 10 ABORTED: too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.
       metrics  ogcineo00ryu  2020-07-07 17:38:08.743  undefined
D      metrics  ogcineo00ryu  2020-07-07 17:38:08.745  Function execution took 8083 ms, finished with status code: 400
```